# Does Jesuit Education not work with Acropolis

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing as Greece, and I took the Jesuit Education (can purchase Campus and Theatre Square buildings with faith), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I have an Acropolis district built in my capital, but it is not showing the Amphitheater as available for purchase with faith.

Is this a bug?  Or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: How much faith do you have currently?

Comment: I've had as much as 1 thousandish without seeing any buildings as an option.  I assumed it worked like purchasing with gold where it would show purchaseable items dithered out if you couldn't afford them.

Answer (score 1):

I think it just doesn't work at all. Jesuit education hasn't offered any purchases to me for any leaders.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue, with a different civ. I also noticed that another building that I don't think should be purchasable with faith is - the Broadcast Center (only in the city with the religion, my other city can only build it normally) My working hypothesis is its misapplying this bonus somehow. I